# Get days in a selected date range for a specific month

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

In Google spreadsheet, in a sheet tab I use a raw list (one entry per line) I've a base data like this:

```
+------------+------------+
|   start    |    end     |
+------------+------------+
| 2016-06-12 | 2016-08-03 |
| 2016-07-12 | 2016-08-03 |
| 2016-07-12 | 2016-07-18 |
+------------+------------+
```

On another tab, same sheet, I've a pull down menu with the name of the months, created with the data validation. What I would like is selecting a month to have the number of days in the date frame for thee selected month.
E.g selecting July, I should have
31 the first line
19 the second line
6 the third line

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the name of the month it in cell C1, try this formula

`=COUNTIF(ArrayFormula(MONTH(A2+ROW(indirect("1:"&B2-A2)))),MONTH(VALUE("01"&$C$1)))`

Unfortunately the INDIRECT function will not work with arrayformula so you will need to copy it down the column.  You can see it working in this example sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eySTFsValIVoq8rmia6RvWWkyEnS9qZfAts4O4w1d78/edit?usp=sharing